# I need to find out if two lists are equal in terms of reference, equal in terms of value or not equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality

```
def type_of_equality(list1, list2):
    new_string = ""
    if list1 == list2:
        new_string += "value"
        return new_string
    elif list1 != list2:
        new_string += "not equal"
        return new_string
    elif list1 is list2:
        new_string += "reference"
        return new_string
```

When I try this

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
print(type_of_equality(x, y))
```

The output should be reference but instead the output is equal. How do I fix this.

Comment: `x == y`. `x is y` too, but that never comes up.

Comment: That's you're checking for the value sooner than the reference!

Comment: Oh I understand. My fault.

Comment: and just return string , no need to +=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check if `list1 is list2` before you check for equality.

When x is y, x always equals y.